# Trouble with declaring a variable

Tags: delphi

This is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

...    

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame2.Show;
end;
```

I got this compiler error:

> Undeclared identifier: 'Frame2'

Then I tried to declare it:

`Frame2: TFrame2;`

### Edit:

Further explenation form comment.

Ok I will be precise. I use anwser ardnew Frame2: TFrame; and I get ** access violation** and with out it I get Undeclared identifier: 'Frame2' now I'm more precise?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Delphi Pascal

Comment: In your OnClick, do you mean `Form2`?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Did you get the same compiler error? Or did the frame not show? Or did you get another error? Please describe exactly what happened.

Comment: -1 for "not working." Be precise.

Comment: Ok I will be precise. I use anwser ardnew **Frame2: TFrame;** and I get ** access violation** and with out it I get **Undeclared identifier: 'Frame2'** now I'm more precise?

Comment: @MarcusAdams No in my Form1. I don't have Form2 only Frame2 and Form1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not show the contents of Unit2, so we can only speculate.  It sounds like there is no `Frame2` global variable declared in Unit2.pas.  That would account for the `undeclared identifier` error.  Declare the variable yourself, and instantiate an instance of the `TFrame2` class before you can then `Show()` it, eg:

```
unit Unit1; 

interface 

uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls; 

... 

implementation 

{$R *.dfm} 

uses
  Unit2; 

var
  Frame2: TFrame2 = nil;

...     

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if not Assigned(Frame2) then
  begin
    Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Self);
    Frame2.Parent := Self;
  end;
  Frame2.Show; 
end;
```

Comment: +1 Yet another option would be to add the frame to the form in the designer and let the framework manage its lifetime

Comment: Answer may be correct, but I see it very necessary to include an example of also freeing `Frame2` when done with it. Anyone who doesn't understand creation most likely won't understand freeing either - they go hand in hand.

Comment: In the example, I use `Self` as the frame's Owner, so there is no need to free it manually. It will be freed when the `TForm` is freed.

Comment: I have problem because I still getting Error "udeclared identifier: ' TFrame2' "

Comment: Then `Unit2.pas` does not declare any `TFrame2` class. What does `Unit2` actually declare? What unit did you actually implement a `TFrame2` class in? Either `Unit2` is not the correct unit you should be using, or `TFrame2` is not the correct class name. You have a mismatch in your setup either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the frame somehow, you can't access it without.

This example presumes you are creating 2 different "TFrame2" instances at once *just temporarily*, then closing (and freeing) them when done (in a try..finally block). There are many other ways of creating and freeing, but the general concept is if you create it, you have to free it...

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F1, F2: TFrame2;
begin
  //You have to first create the instances of "TFrame2"...
  F1:= TFrame2.Create(Self);
  F2:= TFrame2.Create(Self);
  try
    F1.Left:= 0;
    F2.Left:= Self.Width - F2.Width;
    F1.Parent := Self;
    F2.Parent := Self;
    F1.Show;
    F2.Show;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    ShowMessage('There should be 2 instances of "TFrame2" showing on your main form');
  finally
    //And you have to free them when you're done...
    F1.Free;
    F2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or if this "TFrame2" is elsewhere...

```
procedure TForm1.Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Create it first
  Frame2:= TFrame2.Create(Self);
  Frame2.Parent := Self;
  Frame2.Left:= 0;
  Frame2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Destroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(Frame2) then begin
    Frame2.Free;
    Frame2:= nil;
  end;
end;
```

Be careful though, because you might already be creating this "TFrame2"... Go to `Project > Options > Forms` and look to see if "Frame2" is auto-create or not.

Comment: -1. `TFrame` is designed to be embedded in a container window, not shown standalone, and you call `Show` (which is non-modal) but then `Free` the "shown" wrongly used `TFrame` (meaning any click on a control on it is accessing something that doesn't exist any longer and will cause an AV). The use of `Application.ProcessMessages` alone should warrant a second downvote if it was allowed.

Comment: Then perhaps you shouldn't answer questions about them? :) Also, with the exception of the part about needing a container, the rest of my comment would apply to `TForm` as well; you can't `Create`, `Show` and then free them while they're still showing (AVs), and `Application.ProcessMessages` should get a downvote almost automatically (unless you can thoroughly explain why you're using it and the reason is very convincing).

Comment: @Ken, ProcessMessages actually seems appropriate for this example. It calls Show on two controls that might otherwise have been invisible, but to make sure they're fully painted, we process whatever pending messages there are before displaying a message claiming that the frames are visible. After that message, the demo is over, so it's correct to free the controls. They're in local variables, so there will be no further references to them once they're freed. It's also safe to free a visible form. You've criticized this as production code instead of looking at it as a demo of showing controls.

Comment: The concept of the answer was right, but was originally assuming "TFrame2" was a Form, not a Frame. Modified answer, and added another sample.

Comment: @KenWhite And just as Rob explains above, the "Application.ProcessMessages" is a trick to make sure the frames are forcefully shown first before the test message appears. Without it, the message will appear without the frames being shown. And the only thing wrong with my original answer (before edits) was the fact that I was considering "TFrame2" as a "Form" instead of a "Frame".

Comment: @Rob, `Update` on the newly created forms (if they had in fact been forms) would have been sufficient; `ProcessMessages` does a lot more. Re. freeing immediately, this is never proper (even in terms  of the demo), as it sets a bad example (particularly for someone very new to Delphi, as the asker of this question seems to be). A better example, for instance, would have been to create a form, show it modally, and free it afterward, doing it with try..finally. Jerry, the concept wasn't right if you were referencing a frame - af form would  have not answered the question asked.

Comment: In addition, `TFrame` doesn't need to `Show`, anyway; unless it's `Visible` property is false at designtime, it will automatically *show* once it's created and a `Parent` is assigned. An `Update` on the parent window would have sufficed, and is the proper way to do it without resorting to `ProcessMessages`.

Answer (score -3):

I guess it should be declared as

```
Frame2: TFrame;
```

Comment: I got exeption access violation.

Comment: since nobody can see where you are instantiating a TFrame object, and you clearly don't find that sort of thing important enough to post in the original question, I'll assume you aren't doing it

Comment: I don't understand I'm not doing what?

Comment: Instantiating `Frame2` before you `Show()` it.

Comment: -1 because if you're going to answer an unclear question, it needs to at least make sense to the asker - putting myself in the asker's shoes, I would not have a clue what you mean (where to declare?).